# CSS Rotate Being Cropped

Tags: html, css

I have long table and I want to rotate it, the problem is, when I rotate it, it cropped at left. Here's my fiddle:

```css
.rotate {
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

```html
<table class="rotate">
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ametv</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As You can see, the left part of table is cropped. Is there anyway to create this table not cropped? I can't use margin because the content of table various. Sometimes longer or shorter.

Answer (score 0):

By default, elements transform from the center of the element. What you're looking for is to set the transform to originate from the **bottom** of the element, with **[transform-origin: bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)**:

```css
.rotate {
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    
    /* Origin */
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table class="rotate">
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I tried transform-origin but still cropped for a very long table. I try top value but top/left still cropped

Comment: If the above solution does not solve the problem for you, you'll need to provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- the above fixes the problem in the Stack Snippet.

Comment: Oh yup, I see -- it does indeed crop in full page. In the regular snippet, it is fully contained. `transform-origin: bottom` does indeed add about `50px` of margin, and solves it in most cases. In order to push it even further, I believe you'll either need to use some `padding` or `margin`; I don't think there's another option.

Comment: So in other words it is no any solution without margin/padding right?

Comment: I don't believe so, no. If you're worried about the length of your content, you can always use a percentage-based `margin-top` value, or even a value based off of the length of the table's content (using jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

I think calculating the `transform-origin` property values in `px` like the following should fix the issue.

[image: Transform origin]

```js
var height = $(".rotate").outerHeight();

var xaxis = height / 2 + 'px';
var yaxis = height / 2 + 'px';

$('.rotate').css({
  'transform-origin': '' + xaxis + ' ' + yaxis + ' 0px'
});
```

```css
.rotate {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="rotate">
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem
      Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem
      Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit
      Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Ametv</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```